# Missing jwtSecret. Please, set configuration variable "jwtSecret" for the users-permissions plugin in config/plugins.js

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, strapi

I am following this tutorial on Strapi's website: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/amazon-aws.html
to deploy to AWS. It doesn't mention a jwtSecret throughout the entire tutorial but I am getting the error mentioned in the title and I am not sure what to do.

My plugins.js file is the following:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
upload: {
    config: {
        provider: 'aws-s3',
        providerOptions: {
            accessKeyId: env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            secretAccessKey: env('AWS_ACCESS_SECRET'),
            region: env('AWS_REGION'),
            params: {
                Bucket: env('AWS_BUCKET_NAME'),
            },
        },
    },
}});
```

All the variables are declared in my environment file but it doesn't mention a jwtSecret. I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: The error message says that its a config for the users-permissions plugin that is missing, not aws. https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#jwt-configuration

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try adding a new file in '/config' named *plugins.js* with this code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  'users-permissions': {
    config: {
      jwtSecret: env('JWT_SECRET') || crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you consider using typescript, take this snippet:

```js
// path: ./config/plugins.ts

const crypto = require('crypto');

export default ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  'users-permissions': {
    config: {
      jwt: {
        jwtSecret: env('STRAPI_JWT_SECRET') || crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')
      },
    },
  },
});
```