# Missing jwtSecret. Please, set configuration variable "jwtSecret" in Strapi

Tags: heroku, strapi

[Strapi Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9De1s.png)

I am trying to deploy a Strapi app to Heroku. I have set APP_KEYS and JWT_SECRET config vars in Heroku. I have also added this code to plugins.js as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104681/missing-jwtsecret-please-set-configuration-variable-jwtsecret-for-the-users). But I am still getting this error (see image). Can anyone help with this?

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  "users-permissions": {
    config: {
      jwtSecret: env("JWT_SECRET") || crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64"),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I cannot see any image/error. Did you set your environment variable `JWT_SECRET`?

Comment: You can find the image in the Strapi Error link at the top no? I have added the JWT_SECRET in the config vars in Heroku yes

Comment: I didn't see the link above, maybe include the image directly in your question. As for the error: Could you try and see what happens when you hard-code a `jwtSecret` string (just for testing purposes), e.g.: `jwtSecret: "MyJwtSecret1234"`?